# Using skeleton with 24 column grid sytem

Tags: css, grid, responsive-design, 960.gs, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have a photoshop mockup of a website built with the 960gs with 24 columns. I also want it to be responsive with the skeleton boilerplate http://www.getskeleton.com/

Since my design is 24 column based and skeleton supports 16 columns, is there a way to make skeleton work with 24 columns?

Thanks!
marchello

Comment: [have you tried anything](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 3):

Here try this:

https://github.com/dhgamache/Skeleton/pull/103/files

I've already used this in a project and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using this, but some of the column sizes seem off. For example, one-third is still set to 300px...which falls short! How did you calculate these dimensions?

Comment: Why would you even need one-third on a 24 grid? 24 / 3 = 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this: http://factifv3.factiftest.nl/cheatsheet.php it's a variant that expands untill 1440 px. The css is made in sass and extends the code from https://github.com/dhgamache/Skeleton/pull/103/files.